# Caclulate X,Y coordinates of point after rotation around another point of given degrees

Tags: circles, rotations, polar-coordinates

There are Two Points `A` and `B`. The linear distance between the points is `R`.
I have the coordinates of both points given as X and Y values, and these points can be anywhare in on the 2D plane.

I need to rotate Point `A` around point `B` for a given angle (for example 12.56 deg) and get the X and Y coordinates of the new location. The rotation is clockwise.

How can these new X and Y coordinates be calculated?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with rotation matrices?

Comment: Nope, Im a programmer, and not much into mathematics.

Comment: i have tried on paper to make some triangles up based on the horizonal zero, but came nowhere.

Comment: how about vectors?

Comment: @sharkyenergy the two are pretty closely linked, you should not be afraid! And if this is the kind of thing you want to do in programming you'll have to get used to the maths anyway ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If you know how to rotate about the origin, you have to calculate (using  pseudo code notation)
$$(X,Y) = (B_X, B_Y) +  \mathrm{rotate\_origin}(A_X-B_X, A_Y-B_Y)$$

Edit: For 2D rotations you use
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions and remember to convert your angle to radians before using $\cos, \sin.$
$$X = B_X + (A_X-B_X)\cos\phi  - (A_Y-B_Y)\sin \phi $$
$$Y = B_Y + (A_X-B_X)\sin\phi  + (A_Y-B_Y)\cos \phi $$

Comment: Thanks, this was one of my options, problem is i dont know at all how to rotate.. trying to figure it out via web searches but its difficult to find a non-matematician-friendly explanation.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get away from the mathematics!

Comment: not trying to get away, just trying to understand them at a "user friendly" level of rappresentation..

Comment: yay! this is what i needed! thanks!

Comment: Working like a charm! thanks!

Comment: I figured it out myself via the link you provided, but for completness it would be great to add also the formula for the clockwise rotation.

Comment: for clockwise rotation, replace $\phi$ with $-\phi$

Comment: There is IMO no need for separate formula. A clockwise rotation with angle $\phi$ is the same as using a counter-clockwise rotation with $-\phi$.

Comment: Should this not be $$X = B_X + (A_X-B_X)\cos\phi  - (A_Y-B_Y)\sin \phi $$
$$Y = B_Y + (A_X-B_X)\sin\phi  + (A_Y-B_Y)\cos \phi $$? You're subtracting off `B_Y` in all four places....

Comment: @Fake Name:Yes of course, thank you for detecting the typo.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
For rotating a position vector $\vec r$ to $\vec r'$ about the origin by an angle $\theta$, the transformation is given by the matrix $R$:

$$\vec r' =R\vec r=\left(\begin{matrix} \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\ \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \end{matrix}\right)\vec r$$

In your application, the vector $\vec r = \vec a- \vec b$

Answer (score 0):

The rotated coordinates are $x'=x \cos(\theta)-y \sin(\theta)$ and $y'=x \sin(\theta)+y \cos(\theta)$ 
although you'll need to convert you degrees angles to radians first by multiplying by the "degrees to radians" constant first:
$\theta=a \frac \pi{360}$ 
Incase your programming language (you said you were a programmer, i am one too for your notice) doesn't support $\cos$ and $\sin$ by default you can use a different solution.

Comment: No one else used this formula, so it's useful, plus no need for matrices!